# Django: Best way to evaluate condition

Tags: python, django, database

I'm developing an appointments manager for a doctor's office.
There is an option to create a schedule so, for example, if a person wants to come three times a week, (monday, wednesday and friday) at 9:00 starting on 01/02/17 up to 02/24/17 the user can create a schedule by giving just that data: start date, end date, time, days of the week.
The app would alert the user if an appointment is already booked in that time so the user has the option to change the schedule or accept anyway, which will create the schedule skipping the previously occupied appointments.
I'm using django framework to develop the app
In my `Schedule` model I have the following code

```
monday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
tuesday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
wednesday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
thursday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
friday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
saturday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to check if an appointment is already booked between the input dates.

I don't know if the question is clear so I'll leave an example:

*I want to schedule appointments from 01/02/17 to 02/24/17 every tuesday and thursday at 9:00.
An appointment was previously created on 01/19/17 at 9:00 for another patient. The app has to alert this to the user.*

I'd like to know if there is a better way to check this rather than:

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date])
for appointment in appointments:
    if monday and appointment.weekday() == 0:
        check if appointment time == input time
        do something
    elif tuesday and appointment.weekday() == 1:
        check if appointment time == input time
        do something
    elif wednesday and appointment.weekday() == 2:
        check if appointment time == input time
        do something
    elif thursday and appointment.weekday() == 3:
        check if appointment time == input time
        do something
    elif friday and appointment.weekday() == 4:
        check if appointment time == input time
        do something
    elif saturday and appointment.weekday() == 5:
        check if appointment time == input time
        do something
```

Perhaps there is a way to retrieve from the database only the appointments between those dates that have the same time as the input time for the schedule.

Hope this is somewhat understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I understood the problem. But, perhaps, you could associate all days of the week with values, get all days which are true, and then filter appointments by those values:

```
days = [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday]
days = zip(days, range(6))
true_days = [d[1] for d in days if d[0]]
appointments = appointments.filter(weekday__in=true_days)
```

So you would get only those appointments, which weekdays correspond to true weekdays.

EDIT: 
I didn't notice that weekday is a method. You could filter appointments in a loop then:

```
new_appointments = []
for a in appointments:
    if a.weekday() in true_days:
        check if a time == input time
        do something
```